# Python script runs manually but not in cronjob

Tags: cron, python, platform-lsf

So this is a super weird issue. I have a python script that calls many bash commands via subprocess.call based on certain criteria. Now, the script runs just fine manually but when thrown into a cronjob it fails, BUT only when it gets to a certain part of the code. This part of the code runs a `bstat` and a `bkill` command on a user. I've tried using subprocess.call, subprocess.Popen, subprocess.check_output for these two commands and every time it reaches them, it hangs and does nothing. I then get this message in var/spool/mail/root

```
File "/root/Desktop/script.py", line 75, in <module>
    print subprocess.check_output(['bstat' '-q' 'viz' '-u' ,user,])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've tried: using absolute paths for EVERY command possible, changing directories to the directory of the script before running, calling /bin/python before running. I'm at a total loss. What's even more weird, is there are other subprocess.call commands that work just fine when calling a bash script but when it comes to those two commands it doesn't know what to do. Below is the first subprocess command that it hangs on:

`print subprocess.check_output(['bstat' '-q' 'viz' '-u' ,user,])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subprocess call is looking for the `bstat` or `bkill` programs in the `$PATH`... except there is not $PATH` in the cron environment. Specify the full path to those programs, even inside the Python script, and it should work.

Comment: So I've done a ```which bkill``` and ```which bstat``` command and put those full paths in the python script where I call those two commands. But I still get no such file or directory errors. Is there anywhere else I have to define the $PATH

Comment: If the `bkill` and `bstat` programs are in turn scripts, they will likely need a sane environment, including a sane `$PATH`.

Comment: LSF generally requires that the environment configuration in `profile.lsf` has been sourced before the CLI will work.

Comment: @MichaelClosson  answer is what worked for me